# Guardar elementos repetidos en la tabla dinámica Laravel

Tags: php, base-de-datos, laravel-5, eloquent

Estoy trabajando con Laravel y tengo estos modelos (un resumen) con las siguientes relaciones:

```
Table products
  increment id;
  string    description;

Table materials
  increment id;
  string    name;  

Table material_product
  increment id;
  integer   product_id;
  integer   material_id;
  string    dimension;  

class Product extends Model {
    public function materials() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Material::class)->withPivot('dimension');
    }
}

class Material extends Model {
    public function products() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('dimension');
    }
}
```

Estoy usando attach(para guardar) y sync(para actualizar) los datos de mi tabla dinámica, el problema es que en el modelo de negocios de mi app, necesito poder guardar elementos repetidos en mi tabla pivote, por ejemplo:

```
products
+-----+--------------+
|  id | description  |
|-----|--------------+
|  1  | dining table |
+-----+--------------+
```

```
materials
+-----+------+
|  id | name |
|-----|------+
|  1  | wood |
+-----+------+
```

```
material_product
+-----+------------+-------------+-----------+
|  id | product_id | material_id | dimension |
|-----|------------+-------------+-----------+
|  1  |    1       |      1      |   10 x 2  |
+-----+------------+-------------+-----------+
|  2  |    1       |      1      |    5 x 3  |
+-----+------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Entonces ninguno de estos métodos funciona para mí, ya que si envío más de 1 material repetido, solo uno está guarda mi base de datos, ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto? ¿Tienes alguna idea?

Anteriormente estaba realizando lo siguiente:

```
$material= array();

foreach ($request->materials as $val) {
    $material[$val['id']] = ['dimension' => $val['dimension']];
}

$product->materials()->sync($material);
```

Generaba un array antes de usar sync para cada uno de los items, esto funciona cuando no tengo claves iguales en mi arreglo, como saben esto no es posible, pero yo necesito guardar repetidos como mencione anteriormente, entonces cambie el codigo por esto:

```
foreach ($request->materials as $val) {
    $product->materials()->sync($val['id'], ['dimension' => $val['dimension']]);
}
```

Estoy llamando a sync para cada uno de los items de materiales que tengo en mi arreglo que obtengo del request, pero esto tampoco funciona.

Comment: ¿qué has probado y qué mensaje te aparece?

Comment: @Shaz edite mi pregunta con algunas cosas que intente, espero puedas ayudarme

Comment: el primer ejemplo funciona, por que armo el arreglo antes de usar sync, pero con esta opción no puedo armar un arreglo con claves repetidas como necesito. el segundo debería funcionar pero nada, es mas recibo un error de la bd de que el campo "dimension" no puede ir vacío, y los datos del request los recibo correctamente

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estás confundiendo el uso de `sync()` con `attach()`, puesto que la sintaxis que estás usando, es la de attach (para un solo modelo).

Te explico un poco la diferencia entre los dos métodos:

- attach() te permite agregar nuevas relaciones entre modelos, y para columnas adicionales, se emplea la sintaxis:

  ```
  ->attach($val['id'], ['dimension' => $val['dimension']]);
  ```

  Si necesitas agregar más de una relación, usa un array multidimensional:

  ```
  ->attach([
      1 => ['dimension' => 'bla'],
      2 => ['dimension' => 'blabla'],
  ]);
  ```
- sync() está diseñado para «sincronizar» TODAS las relaciones existentes entre dos modelos, en otras palabras, no es necesariamente para agregar, porque también elimina relaciones, al mismo tiempo.

  Los id que no estén en el parámetro de entrada de sync() serán removidos de la tabla pivote.

  La sintaxis para pasar columnas adicionales es igual a la de attach:

  ```
  ->sync([
      1 => ['dimension' => 'bla'],
      2 => ['dimension' => 'blabla'],
  ]);
  ```

Comment: entiendo, el problema es como agregar un arreglo con estos datos ->sync([
    1 => ['dimension' => 'bla'],
    2 => ['dimension' => 'blabla'],
    2 => ['dimension' => 'bloblo'],
]);

Comment: Debería funcionar con attach, con la segunda idea que planteaste, la de iterar y hacer el attach respectivo. Eso sería lo más simple.

Comment: funciona attach, pero lo utilizo al momento de guardar y sync quiero usarlo para actualizar, como dice mi enunciado. esta pregunta hace referencia al mismo problema que tengo, también sin solución https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761880/syncing-multiple-ids-that-are-potentially-duplicate-using-eloquent

Comment: Nunca he intentado algo así con sync, porque no está diseñado para eso, además. lo que se suele hacer cuando la tabla pivote tiene "tanta" autonomía, es manejarlo como un modelo aparte, simplemente, y no complicar la lógica con estos detalles. Teniendo en cuenta que le pusiste un id a la tabla pivote (lo cual no debería hacerse, normalmente), ya le estás dando suficiente autonomía a la tabla, como para que merezca su propio modelo.